# Initialized in initState but late error in didChangeDependencies

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 late bool onoff;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initUser();
  }
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final pro = Provider.of<Pro>(context);
    pro.firstsulonoff = onoff;
  }
  _initUser() async{
    var test = await fireStore.collection('firstsul').doc('firstsul').get();
    onoff = test["onoff"];
```

This is the code that receives Firebase's data from initstate before build is executed and puts it into the firstsulonoff variable of Provider from didChangeDependencies. Late error pops up.

```
  LateInitializationError: Field 'onoff' has not been initialized.
```

Comment: `onoff` is initialized *asynchronously*.  There is no guarantee that it will be initialized before `didChangeDependencies` is called.  Using `late` for asynchronously-initialized variables is a recipe for `LateInitializationError`s.  Either give it a default value or make it nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that `_initUser` should be in `Pro` and the widget should be stateless.